# Parent component not rendering with React Router 4

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I am having trouble rendering a component using react router v4. Is this the correct way to render a single component? I am importing everything correctly; however, there is no error that is helping me check if the Login is showing up correctly. I believe it is a problem with the way I am importing in the  my Login component in AppComponent.

***app.js***

```
ReactDOM.render(
    (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Route path="/" AppStore={AppStore} render={props => <AppComponent {...props} AppStore={AppStore} />} />
        </BrowserRouter>
    ),
    document.getElementById("view-container")
);
```

***AppComponent.js***

```
render () {

    //render
    return (
        <div>
            <main className="container">
                <Route exact path="login" component={Login} />
            </main>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out my error. React Router uses absolute paths
In the AppComponent, you need to set   `<Route path="/login" component={Login} />`